# Split up functionalities across project in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native

Alright so I'm new to React, and have made an application which gets some data from an API and stores it into a table. It worked, but most of the code was in a single file which irritated me a lot. Now I'm trying to split it across multiple files, but without much luck as of yet.

I followed an answer which said I could just create a `APIManager` and use the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

const base_url = 'https://europe-west1-single-router-309308.cloudfunctions.net/GET?';

export let buildURL = (offset, pagination, product_name, store_name) => {
    [...]
}
```

However this gives me a `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. I tried it with a plain function, export function, and this, but nothing works. Should I make a component out of it? This is where the code gets called:

```
<div className='header'>
          <Form handleSubmit={(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name) => {buildURL(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name)}}/>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you importing `buildURL` in your component?

Comment: @digitalbreed `import buildURL from './src/managers/APIManager';`

Comment: You're using a named export. Try either `import { buildURL } from ...` or `import * as APIManager from ...` and change the call to `APIManager.buildURL`.

Comment: Hmm, both don't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with the help of @digitalbreed I managed to fix it! I changed

```
import buildURL from './src/managers/APIManager';
```

to

```
import * as APIManager from './src/managers/APIManager';
```

and changed my reference to the code from

```
<Form handleSubmit={(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name) => { APIManager.buildURL(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name)}}/>
```

to

```
<Form handleSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name)}/>
```

with

```
handleSubmit(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name){
  var url = APIManager.buildURL(offset, pagination, product_name, store_name);
```

And it works fine now. Thanks for the help, digitalbreed!

Comment: Well, with the information given, the named export would be the issue. You did the default import and there probably wasn't any default in your APIManager file.
In your answer, one may ask where `value` is now coming from, but at least it's working for you now! Glad I could be of help.

Comment: Fair point, I modified the method in my code but that doesn't reflect well upon the answer. I've editted it!